# Kendo grid event handling after grid initalisation

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, event-handling, telerik, kendo-grid

I need to bind a function to an event with javascript after the kendo grid is already created. With the purpose of creating a generic state management for the kendo grid. Is their a possible way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the kendo API for binding function handlers to events after the fact.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("edit", function(e) {
    // Something is being edited.
}
```

See jsbin sample http://jsbin.com/civinu/1/edit?js,console,output

Documentation http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/basics/events-and-methods#bind-to-events-after-widget-initialization